# Stair-step line constructing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

For a 2D graph, there are two points, **A** and **B**, and a *set of rectangles* (R<sub>0</sub>, .., R<sub>k-1</sub>).

Starting conditions:

- **A** and **B** are not inside any rectangle.
- Edges of each rectangle are parallel to X-Y axes.

I have to develop an algorithm that constructs a stair-climbing (or step function) line.

The line has to satisfy these constraints:

1. all parts of step line are parallel to X-Y axes
2. the step line doesn't intersect any rectangle
3. step line has minimal length
4. step line has minimal amount of kinks (corners) among all step lines of minimal length

I've read some books on computational geometry, but did not find an algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: What if you have a situation where you can reduce the number of links, but only by increasing the length?

Comment: This is a simple [visability graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_graph) search in a 4-connected (manhattan-distance) descrete 2D space. In the general sense, using A*in a 4-connected space with manhattan-distance as the heuristic/cost should give you the correct solution if distance/kinks are equally weighted.

Comment: If kinks are weighted more than minimum path length, you need to bias the cost function to account for changes in direction and make them more expensive.

Comment: How many rectangles are we talking about? A* seems to be a good idea. You can execute it on a rectilinear grid. The x-coordinates of all rectangles' corners will be the vertical splits of the grid and the y-coordinates the horizontal ones. You just have to efficiently check if a vertex is blocked by a rectangle. This can be achieved with appropriate hash sets.

Comment: @Alexander_KH I've tried to improve the formatting and wording of your question, please let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: @mctylr, thank you very much! It is much better! :)

Comment: @Scott Hunter, thank you for your comment, I've corrected my question. I want to construct a step line which has minimal amount of kinks under conditions 1)-3).

Comment: @aruisdante, thank you very much! But I think, that this solution is too slow for my problem. I want to construct lines which connect rectangles like it is Matlab (Simulink). I think that if there are many rectangles, A* will be slow, am I right?

Comment: @NicoSchertler, we are talking about 70-80 rectangles maximum. But, as I have understood, A* works on a graph. And vertices of that graph will be the pixels of my scheme window, am I correct?

Comment: You don't need every pixel. Just the lines on which there is a corner. That makes a grid less than 160x160 which is a feasible task for A*.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I am sorry, but I still don't understand. What are vertices and edges on graph A* works on?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following scenario:

```
+----+         B
|    |
|    |    
+----+    +-------+
          |       |
  +---+   |       |
  |   |   |       |
  +---+   +-------+

   A
```

There is always a minimal path that goes along the rectangles' edges. In the optimal solution, you could always push a line segment farther to the center of a passing without changing the path length, because the segment before the pushed line segment will be changed by the negative amount of the segment after the pushed line segment.

So in order to run A*, you can generate a grid with vertices at the intersection of rows or columns on which the rectangles' corners lie, plus A and B:

```
o-oo-oo---o----o--o
|    ||   |    |  |
|    ||   |    |  |
o-oo-oo---o----o--o
| || ||   |       |
o-oo-oo---o    o  o
| |   |   |       |
o-oo-oo---o----o--o
| || ||   |    |  |        
o-oo-oo---o----o--o
```

You could even remove vertices that lie within a rectangle. Run A* on that grid with the manhattan distance. In order to reduce kinks, you could introduce an artificial penalty. I.e. when you proceed from a vertex to another vertex in the other direction than you came from, add a very small penalty (e.g. 0.01). This allows you to include kink minimization without changing the penalty for the path length (for sufficiently small kink penalty).

Comment: "There is always a minimal path that goes along the rectangles' edges." What is the proof of this? And how to prove that there is an optimal path which consists of vertices of that grid?

Comment: Maybe this statement was a bit misleading. What I meant is this: If you have a passage between two rectangles, it does not matter where you put the path. Either on one of the edges or somewhere in the middle. Since you only allow axis-aligned movements, changing the position does not change the overall length (assuming that the previous segment and the following segment go in the opposite direction; otherwise the minimal path obviously goes along one edge). Not a full proof, but just the idea.